# What is the "official" way to install LPD without CUPS?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian, printing

I'd like to install LPD (Line Printer Daemon) without installing a full CUPS.
LPD alone is much-much-much smaller than CUPS.
It's for Raspbian (Debian on Raspberry).

In Debian, 2 equivalent packages contain the necessary parts for LPD: `rlpr` and `cups-bsd`
Both contain only 4 executables and the related man pages. But they lack the machinery to run LPQ as a daemon when Linux boot.

Creating myself the systemd service file is easy. But is there an "official" way to run a LPQ daemon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you’re looking for [LPRng](https://tracker.debian.org/lprng). Installing the `lprng` package will give you everything you need to run an LP dæmon.

Comment: I missed this one. I installed the "lpr" package which is smaller/simplier.